# Should I ask a question if I think it may not be answerable?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I recently asked [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/27012/was-a-pair-of-handcuffed-hands-found-near-the-world-trade-center-after-9-11) about 9/11, but I almost considered not asking it because one of the sources of the claim ([Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/rumors/hands.asp)) said that the claim was essentially unanswerable.

As it is, someone else was able to answer my question, but (no offense intended) even that user admitted that information was pretty hard to come by, and also came to the conclusion that the question will most likely never be answered.

Let's say that I find a claim backed up by a bunch of sources. However, perhaps a couple of these sources say that the claim may never be proven or falsified. I start to think that the question is unanswerable.

Should I still ask the question, even though I think it may be impossible to verify or falsify the claim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, yes.

Don't ask questions which are theoretically unanswerable.

Don't ask question which contravene the site rules.

There are other (on-topic) questions which are difficult to answer. If you think they're impossible to answer then you won't be disappointed if they're unanswered, still you may sometimes be pleasantly surprised, that someone is able to provide at least a partial answer.

Comment: Ask it if it's hard, don't ask it if it's impossible, seems a good rule of thumb :-)